# Is there a guide to configuring TPM2 with LUKs in Ubuntu? I have issues!

Tags: package-management, encryption, luks

I am not a beginner but am no way an expert running Linux operating systems.
I am trying to configure a TPM2 with LUKs in Ubuntu to verify its functionality and use disk encryption if possible. I read all you need installed is TPM2-tools and TPM2-TSS and you will be able to take control of your TPM module. Ideally a step by step installation configuration user guide would be great.
I've tried Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu 19.04 and Ubuntu 18.04.6 all installed with LVM and encryption.
I've tried all of this as root and default user with no luck.
I verified that the TMP is present:  "dmesg | grep -i tpm"
[    0.000000] efi:  ACPI 2.0=0x9dbcd000  ACPI=0x9dbcd000  TPMFinalLog=0x9dfa2000  SMBIOS=0x9e3a3000  SMBIOS 3.0=0x9e3a2000  TPMEventLog=0x992f4018
[    0.012066] ACPI: TPM2 0x000000009DBD1F08 000034 (v03 *CHA*  A M I    00000001 AMI  00000000)
[    0.012085] ACPI: Reserving TPM2 table memory at [mem 0x9dbd1f08-0x9dbd1f3b]
[    2.034594] tpm_tis MSFT0101:00: 2.0 TPM (device-id 0x1B, rev-id 22)
1st issue:
Running "sudo apt install tpm2-tools" produces a "TCSD Trousers error: TCSI
Failed to start LSB: starts tcsd"
I ran "sudo apt install LSB" LSB loaded successfully but the same error occurs.
ran "sudo apt install tcsd: {Package not found.
2nd issue:
I went to: https://github.com/vchatterji/tpm2-luks
I installed all of the dependencies for TPM2 tools, downloaded the TPM2-TSS library, extracted it and ran the following:
cd tpm2-tss-1.2.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
cd ...
No errors.
I added myself as a user to the tss group.
I downloaded and extracted tpm2-abrmd.
I ran the following:
cd tpm2-abrmd-1.1.1
./configure --with-dbuspolicydir=/etc/dbus-1/system.d --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/lib/systemd/system --with-udevrulesdir=/etc/udev/rules.d
"configure error: No package 'sapi' found
“make is the next command.  make does not run: "No target specified and makefile found. Stop."
the next command should be:
sudo make install
cd ..
Sorry for the lengthy entry…
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
TerryM